# OpenCV, feature matching with code from the tutorial

Tags: c++, opencv

I copied the code of the [Feature Matching with FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher) from the OpenCV tutorial page, and made the following changes:

- I used the SIFT features, instead of SURF;
- I modified the check for a 'good match'. Instead of

  ```
  if( matches[i].distance < 2*min_dist )
  ```

I used

```
    if( matches[i].distance <= 2*min_dist )
```

otherwise I would get zero good matches when comparing an image with itself.

- Modified parameter in drawing the keypoints:

  ```
  drawMatches( img1, k1, img2, k2,
                   good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
                   vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
  ```

I extracted the SIFT from all the images in the folder Ireland of the [INRIA-Holidays dataset](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/~jegou/data.php). Then I compared each image to all the others and draw the matches.

However there is a strange problem I have never experienced with any other SIFT/Matcher implementation I used in the past:

- the matches for an image I matched against itself are good. Each keypoint is mapped onto itself except for some. See image above. [image: Image matched against itselft]
- When I match I against another image J (with J not equal to I), many points are mapped onto the same one. Some examples are below. 
  [image: Matches] [image: Matches][image: Matches]

Is there anyone who used the same code from the OpenCV tutorial and can report a different experience from mine?

Comment: Search for "ratio test sift"

Comment: I am aware of the ratio test, but I cannot see how it would solve this problem (closest point at distance=0).

Comment: i'm also new for opencv. and wonder if this reason is different detect\descript\match algorithm suits different kinds of picture.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the matcher_simple.cpp example. It uses a brute force matcher that seems to work pretty well. Here is the code:

```
// detecting keypoints
SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);

// computing descriptors
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

// matching descriptors
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

// drawing the results
namedWindow("matches", 1);
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches, img_matches);
imshow("matches", img_matches);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: I did change the matcher, but with no consequences on the matches. The problem is related to many descriptor vectors with all 0s. I have already reported what seems to be a bug.